# Pthread function starting in C

Tags: c, linux, process, operating-system, pthreads

I'm actually new in processes, threads, semaphores, ipc etc(shortly operating system operations on Linux)... My problem is that I compile my code and It simply gets stuck at so funny points. Processes are executed, but they can't enter their threads' function. After that, program directly ends without doing something. I really can't figure out the problem is here or everything have problem. I don't know.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>


void * function1(void *ptr)
{
    printf("Function 1\n");   //!Test prints
    printf("Index is %d",*((int *)ptr));
    sleep(1);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * function2(void *ptr)
{
    printf("Function 2\n");   //!Test prints
    printf("Index is %d",*((int *)ptr));
    sleep(2);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    //...
    int *index;
    int i;
    pid_t f;
    int number_of_process=5;
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    //...

    for(i=0; i<number_of_process; i++)
    {
        f=fork();
        if(f==-1)
        {
         printf("Fork Error!!\n");
         exit(1);
        }
        if(f==0)          //To block child processes re-enter
        {
         *index = i;  //I store index number for each process here. I'll need them in the thread functions
         break;
        }
    }

    /*******************PARENT PROCESS********************/
    if(f!=0){
        // wait for all children to exit
        while (f = waitpid (-1, NULL, 0)){
            if (errno == ECHILD)
            break;
        }
        exit(0);
    }

    /*******************CHILD PROCESS*********************/
    else{
        pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,function1,(void *)index);
        pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,function2,(void *)index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, I forgot to tell that every process consists of 2 threads.

Answer (score 3):

> Processes are executed, but they can't enter their threads' function.
>   After that, program directly ends without doing something.

That's because the main thread (i.e. child process created by `fork()`) doesn't wait for the threads to complete their execution. So it gives you the impression that the program exits without calling all pthread functions.

Use [pthread_join()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) after creating threads:

```
...
pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,function1,(void *)index);
pthread_create(&thread2,NULL,function2,(void *)index);
pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
...
```

The output may be interleaved due to threads printing without any synchronization.

Comment: I did this change. But it still looks same. It does not even waits at sleep function.

Comment: I tested your code and they do sleep(). Add `\n` to your printf() statements in order to flush the output immediately.